# Using reopened standard file descriptors in an iOS app with background capabilities?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to be able to redirect my logging statements to a file so that I can retrieve them when my app runs standalone (i.e. is not attached to Xcode). I have discovered (thank you Stackoverflow) that freopen can be used to accomplish this.

If I create a new Xcode project and add the code to redirect stderr then everything works as expected.

However, when I add the redirection code to my existing, bluetooth project I am having trouble. The file is being created and I can retrieve it using iTunes or Xcode's Devices window, but it is of size 0. If I explicitly close the file then the text that I wrote actually makes it into the file. It is as though iOS is not flushing the file when the app is terminated. I suspect that the trouble stems from the fact that I have enabled background processing. Can anyone help me to understand this?

Here is my code:

```
    let pathes = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true);
    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathes[0]).URLByAppendingPathComponent("Test.log")
    freopen(filePath.path!, "a", stderr);

    fputs("Hello, Samantha!\r\n", stderr);

    struct StderrOutputStream: OutputStreamType {
        static let stream = StderrOutputStream()
        func write(string: String) {fputs(string, stderr)}
    }
    var errStream = StderrOutputStream.stream
    print("Hello, Robert", toStream: &errStream)

    fclose(stderr) // Without this the text does not make it into the file.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd leave this as a comment, but have you looked into `NSFileHandle`? It sounds like you just need a way to append data to the end of a text file, correct?

Once you have a handle with something like `NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL:)`, you can use `.seekToEndOfFile()` and `.writeData(_:)`. As a side note, you'll need to convert your String to Data before writing it.

Admittedly, this will probably end up being more lines of code, and you'll almost certainly need to take threading into consideration.

Comment: Thanks @caseynolan. I've pretty much decided to create my own logging class (myLogger.Log() instead of print() or NSLog()). My logger will open and write a file (similar to what you describe) in addition to writing the console. What I do not like about this is that my code will now be "littered" with calls to myLogger and will hence not be as shareable as it might otherwise be.